# $\mathbb{E}|Z_{p_i}-1|\to 0 \implies \mathbb{E}|Z_{p}-1|\to 0$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expected-value

Suppose we have a sequence of random variables, $$ (Z_p)$$ with $$\mathbb{E}Z_p=1,\qquad Z_p\ge 0 \quad a.s. $$ and $$ Z_p\to 1 \quad \text{in probability}$$

We can chose a subsequence, $Z_{p_i}$ such that $$\mathbb{P}(|Z_{p_i}-1|>1/i)<1/i $$ then $$Z_{p_i}\to 1 \quad a.s.$$  By Sheffe's lemma, we have $$\mathbb{E}|Z_{p_i}-1|\to 0 $$.

The question now is, can we conclude that$$\mathbb{E}|Z_{p}-1|\to 0 $$

Comment: A sequence of reals converges to $a \in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if every subsequence contains a subsequence converging to $a$.

Comment: @d.k.o. I see.  This is certainly true in our case, as the convergence in probability allows us to repeat the construction in any subsequence. Thank you